# Just registered GitLab runner and getting Authentication failure when using shell type

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Just installed GitLab runner service and tried to run a basic job.

I got the following output:

Password: su: Authentication failure
ERROR: Job failed: prepare environment: exit status 1. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information

Googling, I found that the contents of the .bash_logout may be a problem, but my .bash_logout was blank. I created and added ssh keys for the gitlab-runner user, and was able to manually clone via ssh, but I can't get the job to run. Anyone experienced this that can offer a suggestion?

Comment: Same issue. After I improved the Docker security for example, after I set "no-new-privileges" to false and "userns-remap" to default (namespace remapping) in the Docker daemon.

Comment: I also think it's wise to not use shell runners, but use directly Docker runners instead under GitLab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was in the pam file. root couldn't su to gitlab-runner

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer should definitively by improved!? This is not helping me enough. Give more details and info. And links to docs.

Answer (score 1):

Background story: GitLab runner is running as root user, in order to retrieve for example the `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` file. If your gitlab-runner is already running rootless you might want to remove the `--user gitlab-runner` from the systemd service file. However, most likely your Gitlab Runner is running as root.

If you increase the security on your host machine and disable the root user and the `su` command. You could enable this again by editing `/etc/pam.d/su` file and set:

```
auth       sufficient pam_rootok.so
```

Or only allow the root user to use the `su` command to only switch to the gitlab-runner user (without password):

```
auth  [success=ignore default=1] pam_succeed_if.so user = gitlab-runner
auth  sufficient                 pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user = root
```